# CSS: Add border with animation left to right | right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to build a tabbed div container:

[image]

At the moment it looks like this. I can also switch the tab. Each tab has an `is-active` class.

To show the user which tab is active, I've added a border under each tab. When I change tab now, the border get's hardly changed. So removed from the left one and added to the right one.

Because this looks not so pretty I thought "Is it possible to add the border with an animation sliding from the left to the right or back to the left when pressing the tab title?"

So it should looks like fading from tab to the other one. Any idea how to deal with this?

This is my simplified code:

```js
jQuery("ul.tabs li").click(function(){
  var e = jQuery(this).attr("aria-controls");
  jQuery(this).hasClass("active")||(jQuery("li").removeClass("active"),jQuery(this).addClass("active"),jQuery("#"+e).show())})
```

```css
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    display: flex;
}

ul.tabs li {
  flex-grow: 50;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
    cursor: default;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs wc-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="description_tab active" id="tab-title-description" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-description"> 
    <a href="#tab-description">Beschreibung</a>
  </li>
  <li class="reviews_tab" id="tab-title-reviews" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-reviews">
    <a href="#tab-reviews">Fragen / Antworten</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes,you can do it using an extra tag. Call it as a `slider` for now.

So, now if you click on the slider will move to and fro.

Here is code attached.

```js
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('Tab');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, function(tab) {
 tab.addEventListener('click', setActiveClass);
});

function setActiveClass(evt) {
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, function(tab) {
  tab.classList.remove('active');
 });
 
 evt.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.Tabs {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.Tabs:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
 }

.description_tab {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  text-align: center;
 }

.description_tab:first-child.active ~ .slider {
   left: 0;
  }

.description_tab:nth-child(2).active ~ .slider {
   left: 33.333%;
  }

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #4A66F4;
  transition: left .25s;
 }

.Tab {
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
}

.Tab > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  transition: color .15s;
 }

.Tab.active > a {
   color: #222;
  }

.Tab:hover > a {
   color: #222;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<ul class="Tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="description_tab active Tab" id="tab-title-description" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-description"> 
    <a href="#tab-description">Beschreibung</a>
  </li>
  <li class="description_tab Tab" id="tab-title-reviews" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-reviews">
    <a href="#tab-reviews">Fragen / Antworten</a>
  </li>
<li class="slider" role="presentation"></li></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helped you, 
Thank you.

Credits: [from earth on codepen](https://codepen.io/everdimension/pen/xZLggo/?editors=1010)